# Basic abridged suttas in English and only English for chanting along with TTS

Tags: sutras, chanting, english

I can't find concise suttas in English anywhere. I found them before Google and Bing changed so that you can't find anything.

By basic I mean all the suttas that you would hear at a meditation retreat or an extended retreat of 3 years. They don't have to be abridged. I just find short suttas more chantable. I like to understand them. I think maybe uderstanding the suttas as you chant them is just crazy enough to work.

Just the English unless...

Well, playing each Pali sentence with the English just throws me off unless the English is aligned with the Pali in such a way as to sound grammatically incorrect but understandable. That for me helps me understand the Pali because the English words are flowing in the same order as the Pali words.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to "[A Chanting Guide](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0000.html)" by The Dhammayut Order in the USA.

I think it has everything that you asked for, including Pali and English translation.

Some of it has been made more concise.

For e.g. the [Five Subjects for Frequent Recollection](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/ChantingGuide/Section0007.html).

You can play the audio (using the [image] button on the left of the title). The audio includes chanting in both Pali and English.

The page includes Pali and English translation.

This is the concise version of [AN 5.57](https://suttacentral.net/an5.57/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false).

Comment: That's the best one so far. I think it has its own tts with the Pali but the English words don't appear to align word for word with the Pali. Not that an alignment like that could be perfectly aligned all the time. I didn't mean aligned by sentence but by each word that might be sometimes impossible but this is pretty good. Maybe there is a way to format if you want to hear the Pali or the English first or last or at all and just leave one or the other language. Thanks 

Comment: Yeah maybe the word for word thing was too much to hope for. It looks like it does do some different formatting. Thank you